# Scaling property of Dirac delta function is not intuitive!

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

It is known that the Dirac delta function scales as follows:$$\delta(kx)=\frac{1}{|k|}\delta(x)$$
I have studied the proof for it, considering Dirac delta function as a limit of the sequence of zero-centred normal distributions (as given [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Scaling_and_symmetry)).

However, when intuitively thought about it, this does not seem correct. Since $\delta(x)$ is zero everywhere except at $x=0$, $\delta(kx)$ should also be zero for any non-zero value of $x$ (given $k\in R-\{0\}$). Also for $x=0, kx=0$, and, thus, $\delta(kx)=\delta(x)$.

From the above logic it is evident that the scaling property should be the following.$$\delta(kx)=\delta(x)\forall x\in R, k\neq 0$$
However, as we know this is not true, can you point out where I am going wrong in thinking like this. Please note that I do not require some other kind of proof (until necessary), just a flaw in this kind of thinking.

Comment: When you plug in specific numbers, as in "for $x=0$, $kx=0$ and, thus, $\delta(kx)=\delta(x)$", you're treating $\delta$ as if it were a function.  It's not a function, and treating it as one can lead to error.

Comment: As a comment, perhaps the more intuitive way for a physicist is just to write $\delta_0 = H'$, the derivative of the heaviside function. Since $H(kx) = H(x)$ when $k>0$, you easily deduce the result.

Comment: Notice that using your intuitive reasoning also $\delta(x/k)=\delta(x)$ which leads to a contradiction with $\delta(kx)=\delta(x)$ unless $k=1$.

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4627880/2513 ; https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439535/squarable-but-not-differentiable-delta-function

Answer (score 7):

> However, when intuitively thought about it, this does not seem correct. Since $\delta(x)$ is zero everywhere except at $x=0$, $\delta(kx)$ should also be zero for any non-zero value of $x$ (given $k\in R-\{0\}$). Also for $x=0, kx=0$, and, thus, $\delta(kx)=\delta(x)$.

Also $C \, \delta(x)$ is zero everywhere except at $x=0.$ Why do you think that $\delta(kx)$ must be $\delta(x)$ and not $C\,\delta(x)$ for some $C\neq 1$?

You know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) \, dx = 1.$ But if $k>0$ we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(kx) \, dx
= \left\{ x=\frac{y}{k} \right\}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(y) \, \frac{dy}{k}
= \frac{1}{k} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(y) \, dy
= \frac{1}{k}
$$
Therefore $\delta(kx)$ can not equal $\delta(x)$ but rather equals $\frac{1}{k} \delta(x).$

You can also look at ordinary functions that that approximate $\delta,$ e.g.
$$
d_\epsilon(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\text{ if $-\epsilon<x<\epsilon$}\\
0\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
You have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d_\epsilon(x) \, dx = 1.$ But if you scale it in the $x$ direction you get another integral,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d_\epsilon(kx) \, dx
= \left\{ x=\frac{y}{k},\ k>0 \right\}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d_\epsilon(y) \, \frac{dy}{k}
= \frac{1}{k} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d_\epsilon(y) \, dy
= \frac{1}{k}.
$$

Comment: "Why do you think that δ(kx) must be δ(x) and not Cδ(x) for some C≠1?" I think so beacuse for x=0, δ(kx)=δ(x)=δ(0); but Cδ(x)=Cδ(0).

Comment: @BigBrother. On the other hand, $\delta(0) = \infty = C \infty = C \, \delta(0).$ As you hopefully understand, one cannot handle $\delta$ as a pointwisely defined function.

Comment: @md2perpe one can: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439535/squarable-but-not-differentiable-delta-function

Comment: Why the substitution $x\to y/k$ is permitted here? It seems ad-hoc and unjustified.

Comment: Substitution does not come automatically from the definition of distributions, but there is a natural definition based on how it works for integrals of ordinary functions. My last equation, where I integrate an [approximation to the identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Approximations_to_the_identity) therefore works as a justification.

Comment: @Anixx. What you are talking about in your post is not the Dirac delta distribution but something else. That thing might have other rules than the Dirac delta distribution.

Comment: @md2perpe and that definition of scaling for $\delta(x)$ is counter-intuintive, actually. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814228/scaling-property-of-dirac-delta-function-is-not-intuitive This $\overline{\delta}(x)$ distribution has the intuitive scaling property.

Comment: I was told that the equivalence of distributions follows fro equivalence of their functionals. Since both $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)f(x)dx=f(0)$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \overline{\delta}(x)f(x)dx=f(0)$, the distributions are equal. But I doubt this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627880/is-overline-deltafx-deltafxfx-a-function-rather-than-distribu

Comment: @Anixx. The scaling property might be counter-intuitive if you think of $\delta$ as a function having an infinite value at origin and using $c\infty=\infty$ for all $c\neq 0.$ But $\delta$ shouldn't be thought of as a function with point-wise values (especially not at origin).

Comment: Is $\bar\delta$ a functional? What is its definition? I cannot see any definition in your posts.

Comment: It is claimed that this scaling property was introduced to make delta more like a function: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4628151/2513 In my opinion, it makes it less like a function.

Comment: Which of the first definitions do you choose? They are not equivalent.

Comment: The second one follows from the first one in case where the function $f$ is differentiable and is not constant zero on an interval (when this condition is not met, it can be used to generalize the first definition).

Comment: A typo... Should be $$\int_a^b \overline{\delta}(f(x))g(x)dx=\int_a^b \delta(f(x))|f'(x)|g(x)dx$$ or piecewise $$\overline{\delta}(x)={\begin{cases}\frac1\pi\int_0^\infty dx,&{\text{if }}x=0\\ 0,&{\text{if }}x\ne 0.\end{cases}}$$ From the first definition it follows that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \overline{\delta}(x) g(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) g(x)dx=g(0)$$

Comment: The piecewise definition only says that $\bar\delta(0)=\infty$ and $\bar\delta(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0.$ Or do you have a special meaning of $\int_0^\infty \, dx$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\delta$ is a distribution, you need to phrase everything in that language. You can't just go around evaluating it. If you're viewing $\delta(x)"="\infty$ at $x=0$, then of course you cannot distinguish between $\delta(0),$ $|k|\delta(0),$ etc. This is the reason that you're having trouble with intuition. First, I'll give a more formal explanation to the general reader, then I'll address "intuition" a little bit more.

Observe that for any $\varphi\in C_c^\infty$ and $f\in L^1_{loc}$, $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(kx)\varphi(x)\, dx=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{k}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\varphi(y/k)\, dy && k>0\\
\frac{1}{k}\int\limits_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(y)\varphi(y/k)\, dy && k<0
\end{cases}$$ That is,

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(kx)\varphi(x)\, dx=\frac{1}{|k|}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\varphi(y/k)\, dy.$$ This motivates the *definition* for general distributions, such as the Dirac delta. Alternatively, check out a dense subspace and extend by density.

If you want something less rigorous, see e.g. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Scaling_Property_of_Dirac_Delta_Function

The Dirac delta will not follow standard intuition due to the fact that it's not a "simple" object, like a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. For this reason, I'd argue that a derivation like this, or the one that you linked, give the desired intuition. It probably makes the most sense to think about it from the perspective of a regularizing sequence like you linked and observing the property from there. This gets much more at how $\delta$ behaves.

Comment: What you wrote is correct but I seriously doubt that the person asking the question has the mathematical level to understand your answer.

Comment: This is potentially true, but I think that it could be helpful to a reader other than just the OP who looks for a question like this :)

Comment: "This motivates the definition for general distributions" - but this does not work even for general functions. And the distributions are a superset of functions, no?

Comment: @Anixx fixed, thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1):

A bit belatedly: in addition to other good answers, indeed this is a good time to see that it is simply not sustainable (and not useful!) to insist on a notion of "function" for $\delta$ that pretends that it is describable by pointwise values.

Yes, this is possibly heretical after all the drill about "what functions are", in very-basic calculus and analysis. But, perhaps unsurprisingly, those definitions are excellent *in_a_certain_regime* ... and this was a big step forward 100+ years ago! ... but inadequate for talking about Heaviside's, Dirac's, and others' *generalized* functions. L. Schwartz' rigorization of most of those ideas accomplished many things, but it did *not* manage to save the idea that a function is described by pointwise values.

There are at least two styles of "intuition" that seem to suggest a way to get correct outcomes. (After all, we are talking about computations that refer to real things! ...) One is thinking of $\delta$ as a ("weak") limit of "spike" functions (which do have pointwise values), to prove its properties. Another is to repackage that weak-limit game (which is arguably not physically explanatory to many...?) as something about infinitesimals, and the behavior of $\delta$ "infinitesimally near $0$".

From an optimistic viewpoint, these two ideas are "the same", for me.

Formally, they are certainly different. The infinitesimal approach has some annoying technical limitations, but it *does* approximately restore the idea that even generalized functions have pointwise values... but with complications in the notion of "pointwise" and "values". :)

Comment: "it is simply not sustainable (and not useful!) to insist on a notion of "function" for δ that pretends that it is describable by pointwise values." - why? It is absolutely sustainable and useful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439535/squarable-but-not-differentiable-delta-function

Answer (score 1):

The most intuitive way I can think of it uses the notion of the delta function as a rectangular function of area 1 whose X dimension approaches 0, and whose Y dimension approaches infinity.

Since the rectangle is infinitely tall and infinitesimally skinny, scaling the height or the width still results in a rectangle that is infinitely tall and infinitesimally skinny.

However, scaling x by 2 would make the rectangle half as wide, which cuts the area in half. The same area can be achieved by making the rectangle half as tall, in other words by dividing the output of the function by 2.

It becomes an issue of preserving the property that the area of the delta function is 1.

In summary: making the delta function skinnier is equivalent to making the delta function shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my understanding which helps me memorize the scaling property of (t).

Considering the physical meaning of (t) is to introduce a model that can model the reaction toward some stimulus, like adding a voltage on a capacitor, when the slope is infinitely large and the action time is infinitely small.

So we can easily know that no matter the function is (at) or (t), the systems always give reaction to the stimulus at the same time. So, the range of t doesn't change. (at) and (t) have the same range of t.

(t) can be shaped as a rectangle or something else, it doesn't matter which shape you choose. Nevertheless, let's suppose its shape is a rectangle. Since the range of time doesn't change, the bottom line of  (at) will expand a times. Since the total area is constant, the height of this rectangle should be 1/a. Consequently, (at) = (1/a)*(t)