# Where the scaling property $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ax)dx=\frac1a \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ comes from in the theory of distributions?

Tags: distribution-theory

Where the scaling property $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ax)dx=\frac1a \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ comes from in the theory of distributions?

Basically, if the distributions are defined as linear maps $f:\psi \in {\mathcal {D}}(\mathbb {R} )\to\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\psi(x)dx\in\mathbb{R}$, where the scaling property comes from? Or it is a separate postulate?

Comment: Is this not just change of variables from ax -> x?

Comment: @CaptainChicky Why such change of variables should be permitted?

Comment: @CaptainChicky where is the proof of change of variable theorem for improper integrals of distributions? For instance, here is a proof for Riemann integrable functions on a finite interval: http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/tm/34/tmn34p25-28.pdf

Comment: It is not a postulate, but a definition indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So first, rigorously speaking, integrals are not defined for distributions. A distribution $\boldsymbol f$ (over $\Bbb R$) is indeed a linear form that to any $\varphi\in\mathcal D(\Bbb R)$ associates a value $\langle \boldsymbol f,\varphi\rangle\in\Bbb R$ (that is sometimes also denoted $\boldsymbol f[\varphi]$).

- Now, to make these linear forms behave as a generalization of functions, one associates to any function $f$ a distribution $\boldsymbol f$ defined by
  $$
  \langle \boldsymbol f,\varphi\rangle := \int_{\Bbb R} f(x)\,\varphi(x)\,\mathrm d x.
  $$
  Here I put a bold font to distinguish the function and the distribution, but in general one uses the same notation, and considers functions as a particular case of distributions (a bit as rational numbers are a particular case of real numbers, but they are formally usually initially build differently).
- But there are others distributions such as $\delta_0$ that are not functions, and for example its distributional derivative acts as $\langle\delta_0',\varphi\rangle = -\varphi'(0)$ which is not an integral. However, because of the fact that brackets denote the integral in the case of functions, we can *think of them* as being the analogue of the integral for other distributions.

Now that objects are more clear, you see that in principle, if $\boldsymbol f$ is a distribution, there is no meaning yet to $\boldsymbol f(ax)$ (and even no meaning either to $\boldsymbol f(x)$). Let me define $\tau_a$ the operation $\tau_a f(x) = f(ax)$. If we want to use the analogue of a change of variable formula for distributions, we should indeed define what it means first. To be consistent with the change of variable formula in integrals, it is defined by
$$\label{1}\tag{1}
\langle \tau_a\boldsymbol f,\varphi\rangle := \frac{1}{|a|}\langle \boldsymbol f,\tau_{1/a}\varphi\rangle,
$$
so that indeed, when $f$ is a function, this is consistent with the formula
$$
\int_{\Bbb R} f(ax)\,\varphi(x)\,\mathrm d x = \frac{1}{|a|}\int_{\Bbb R} f(x)\,\varphi(x/a)\,\mathrm d x.
$$

In the particular case when $\boldsymbol f$ is a compactly supported distribution, then one can take $\varphi = 1$ and define the analogue of the integral of $f$ by
$$
\int_{\Bbb R} \boldsymbol f := \langle \boldsymbol f,1\rangle,
$$
and your formula follows taking $\varphi = 1$ and $a>0$ in \eqref{1}, giving
$$
\int_{\Bbb R} \tau_a\boldsymbol f = \frac{1}{a} \int_{\Bbb R} \boldsymbol f
$$
since $\tau_{1/a}1 = 1$.

Comment: But this definition of scaling is counter-intuitive and not as a function would behave. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814228/scaling-property-of-dirac-delta-function-is-not-intuitive

Comment: I do not see your point. If $f$ is a function, then the relation (1) is always true. This is how a function behaves ... And I do not see the problem with your link. The answers to this question seem clear to me, and indicate that it is indeed intuitive when you start to understand the concept ... Another way to say it: give me any other definition you would find intuitive, and check if it works when $f$ is a function ;)

Comment: "If f is a function, then the relation (1) is always true." - no. Here is an example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4627880/2513

Comment: More on this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439535/squarable-but-not-differentiable-delta-function

Comment: $\overline{\delta}$ is a function.

Comment: For functions the relations $f(ax)=f(x)$ for all $x$ is totally OK. For instance, the sign function satisfies it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142429/discussion-between-ll-3-14-and-anixx).

Comment: $\overline{\delta}(x)$ is defined in the links.

Comment: (+1) I always enjoy your posts on distribution theory.  Well done here on the definition of the "shifting operator" as applied to a distribution.